# Bootstrap scrollspy not working and nav menu buttons are causing the header to reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Basically all anchor hrefs work except that the scrollspy is not working. Data-offset is not working also.On click only the first `li` 'Home' is changing its background all others are not working. When scrolling down to `#search-nav` `#obqvi` `#about` and so on menu buttons related to them are not getting colored also so this means my scrollspy is not working at all.

Also when i click one of the anchors the whole header menu buttons reload it happens for around 0.1s but its ugly.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy this is the link im using as template and i cannot see any difference compared to my code

HTML :

```
    <body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="0">
            <header>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                                </button>
                                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo-img" src="images/logo.png" alt="logo"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#search-nav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#obqvi"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Sales</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#about"><span class="fa fa-cogs"></span> Services</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#footer-contact-form"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#end-footer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span> About Us</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </nav>
            </header>
....
```

Edited with Jquery script but it still does not work when i click on 'a' i get smooth scrolling to the position thats alright 
but when i scroll with the scrollwheel the button related to the section doesnt get colored and on click also it doesnt get colored

JS:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){

                $('.btn-information').click(function(){
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                });             
                 // Add scrollspy to <body>
            $('body').scrollspy({ target: ".navbar", offset: 50 });

            // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
            $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function (event) {

                // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                event.preventDefault();

                // Store hash
                var hash = this.hash;

                // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 800, function () {

                    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            position: relative;
        }

        #search-nav {
            padding-top: 50px;
            height: 500px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #1E88E5;
        }

        #obqvi {
            padding-top: 50px;
            height: 500px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #673ab7;
        }

        #about {
            padding-top: 50px;
            height: 500px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #ff9800;
        }

        #footer-contact-form {
            padding-top: 50px;
            height: 500px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #ff9800;
        }

        #end-footer {
            padding-top: 50px;
            height: 500px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: #ff9800;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#search-nav"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#obqvi"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Sales</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about"><span class="fa fa-cogs"></span> Services</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#footer-contact-form"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#end-footer"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-link"></span> About Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="search-nav" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 1</h1>
        <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="obqvi" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 2</h1>
        <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="about" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-contact-form" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="end-footer" class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Section 3</h1>
        <p>Click on the different Section links in the navbar to see the smooth scrolling effect.</p>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Add scrollspy to <body>
            $('body').scrollspy({ target: ".navbar", offset: 50 });

            // Add smooth scrolling on all links inside the navbar
            $("#myNavbar a").on('click', function (event) {

                // Prevent default anchor click behavior
                event.preventDefault();

                // Store hash
                var hash = this.hash;

                // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
                // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 800, function () {

                    // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
                    window.location.hash = hash;
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice - but when i did it i found that i had to include this as well - to make sure the hamburger nav menu (in mobile viewport size)  closed on the click event. // Closes the Responsive Menu on Clicking the Menu Item $('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() { $('.navbar-toggle:visible').click(); });

Comment: well your code works only for smooth scroll animation the buttons dont get background-colored and if i just scroll then and not click on any a the buttons again dont get background-colored the scrollspy makes buttons colored when the user scroll to particular section and when i click on any a the button clicked must stay colored too

Comment: this  works for me - ignore my post and go with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will help, but I had to include the following in my js when I was using a scroll spy function. Also - check that you have the required files for the scroll spy to work and that jquery is loaded and called into the page first.

```
// jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

// Highlight the top nav as scrolling occurs
$('body').scrollspy({
    target: '.navbar-fixed-top'
})
```

Comment: so you say i delete all attributes and use your script 
and i need to include the Jquery Easing plugin and all my bootstrap Jquery  and Jquery plugin in header not after the content in the body

Comment: dammit - ignore this comment- i got confused !! :) but you will ned to call the jquery and wrap the functions in a "document ready" and you will need to required files. But if you add the code privided it should work

Comment: wrapped in document ready i know that but still it does not work what you mean by rquired files

Comment: as in my post - // jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin

Comment: it does not work i downloaded this plugin and included correctly i copy pasted your code and didnt removed body attributes and it still does not work it stays the same no colored anchors on click and on scroll down

Comment: forget my stuff - go with @kblau as is described. It works and also for me - does change the background color of the links on the scroll  (from #222222 to #080808)